# How to show cities on a drop down menu according to the selected country? angular 4

Tags: jquery, arrays, angular, web-services, filter

I'm connecting to a web service to get countries and cities in 2 drop down menus one for countries and one for cities, now i want the selection of the first drop down menu (countries) to open the array of the specific country to show the cities related to this country only not all the cities, so i need to pull the cities array which inside the chosen country array from the web service, any ideas how to do it dynamically? here is the code that i can share with you, i cannot share more than this because it belongs to my company but you can just write the right syntax to me and describe how to do it dynamically and i will do the rest:

```
<select name="city" class="rounded-inputs20 select-select col-md-3">
    <option value="Country" selected="selected">Country</option>
  <option *ngFor="let country of countries.data"  value="countries">{{country.name}}</option>
  </select>

  <select id="sel1" name="Country" class="rounded-inputs20 select-select col-md-3">
    <option value="City" selected="selected">City</option>
    <option *ngFor="let city of countries.data[0].cities" value="cities">        {{city.name}}</option>  

  </select>
```

if anything not cear just comment and i will provide you with more description

Comment: What if **no country** is **selected** yet the **cities** have to be an **empty array**?

Comment: yes, empty array.

Comment: Posted an answer hope it helps

Comment: Check this : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dropdown

Comment: @br.julien this is awesome but im pulling data from a web service so i need to identify which array to put in the city part based on the country, any ideas?

Comment: @br.julien Thank you so much, i edited the code to pull from the web service, thank you so much for your help because u built a new project just to guide me through it, so, thaaaaanks ^_^

Answer (score 0):

First of all the ***ngFor** for your select elements is wrong.It should be like this (note that you can change the value from **country.name** to whatever property you want from your country object):

```
<option *ngFor="let country of countries.data"  value="{{country.name}}">{{country.name}}</option>
```

To see what value is selected you can add **onChange** method to your select element, so you'll have something like:

```
<select name="city" class="rounded-inputs20 select-select col-md-3" (change)="onCountryChange($event.target.value)">
```

and then in your **.ts** file you can call another service based on the selected country or filter the existing list of cities.

```
onCountryChange(country: string): void {
  // get cities based on country OR filter existing cities array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So first you get the change:

In your html:

```
<select name="city" (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)" class="rounded-inputs20 select-select col-md-3">
```

In your component:

```
private cities: any[] = [];

constructor(){}

private onSelect(_country: any){
      this.cities = this.countries.data.filter((country: any) =>
           country.name  === _country);
```

Now you can do an ngFor on **cities.cities**:

```
<option *ngFor="let city of cities.cities" value="city">
```

Comment: Your answer is right i think but can you please post the full code?

Comment: This is all I can do for you.

Comment: I meant the edit is all I can do for you :P You should be able to copy paste it and it should work. **In the question**  **name=''''** is changed around keep that in mind.